# UITableView Swipe to Delete Button Not Showing Up

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have done this hundreds of time but currently, I have no idea why the Delete button is not showing up when I swipe from right to left.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {


        }

    }
```

I have implemented the commit tableView delegate which makes the delete button appears automatically. But for some reason it does not do anything. Delete button never shows up.

Every time I swipe the segue gets fired and it takes me to a separate screen.

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showOrderDetails" {

            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
                return
            }

            let order = self.orders[indexPath.row]

            let placeOrderTVC = segue.destination as! PlaceOrderTableViewController
            placeOrderTVC.order = order 

        }
    }
```

Comment: sometimes if you have gestures in the cell then it might be hard to trigger the editing mode (I mean if you have all the needed code to show the delete action)

Comment: @zombie I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this before, you need to implement the editActionsForRowAt delegate method. It seems sometimes this is required and other times it isn't.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
  let result = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {
    (_, indexPath) in
    //Delete from your data structure here
  }

  return [result]
}
```

The canEditRowAt datasource method is defaulted to true so I've never been required to implement that method.

Comment: This method is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code, you need to write canEditRowAt delegate also**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // handle delete
    }
}
```